# [$sce:iequirks] Strict Contextual Escaping does not support Internet Explorer version < 9 in quirks mode

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer-7, quirks-mode

Once I upgrade AngularJS from 1.0.7 to 1.2.0rc1 I get the following error:

```
[$sce:iequirks] Strict Contextual Escaping does not support Internet Explorer version < 9 in quirks mode
```

- I have already added `<!doctype html>` but to no avail.
- I also need to support IE7 (sob).

Comment: **Note**: `$sce` is on by default in 1.2.0. For more information on `$sce` check the [API Reference](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$sce).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the [github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3633) related to this problem - `$sce` does **not** support IE7 in standards mode.

> The minimum bar for $sce is IE8 in standards mode.  IE7 standards mode
>   is not supported.  If you must support IE7, you should disable $sce
>   completely.

To disable `$sce`:

```
angular.module('ie7support', []).config(function($sceProvider) {
  // Completely disable SCE to support IE7.
  $sceProvider.enabled(false);
});
```

Comment: Even after disabling $sce it still gives the error for me

Comment: Check that you don't have compatibility view turned on in IE. Also note that angular [dropped IE8 support in v1.3](http://angularjs.blogspot.co.uk/2014/10/angularjs-130-superluminal-nudge.html). hth.

Answer (score 2):

This has been answered, but somebody might find this useful:
in IE(8) turn off Compatibility View - that "broken page" icon after address bar