# AngularJS does not work in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: angularjs

I have a AngularJS page that I am attempting to display in IE 8.
Below is my HTML

```
<html id="ng-app" ng-app="">
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json3/3.3.0/json3.min.js'></script>
<script src="http://docs.angularjs.org/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<BODY ng-app="">
<script type="text/javascript">
function cstScope($scope) {
    $scope.LEVEL = "x1        ";
    $scope.change = function() {
        alert("changed");
    };
}
</script>
<div ng-controller="cstScope">
<input type=text ng-model="LEVEL" ng-change="change()"></input>
</div>
</BODY>
</html>
```

It falls over when the page is loading with

```
Line: 30
Error: [$sce:iequirks] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.14-build.2316+sha.24fe163/$sce/iequirks
```

I have tried adding JSON3 and ieshiv but no luck.

Comment: Take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18506458/sceiequirks-strict-contextual-escaping-does-not-support-internet-explorer-ve.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add this meta tag  in inside of Header tag

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
```

Look like

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Sample App</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
</head>
```

I hopes, it's helps to you. Cheer's...

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you. But you need to version < 2.0 of jquery too. I am posting the complete solution in the comment below which worked for me.

Comment: Excellent Answer @Ramesh Rajendran. Its working like a charm.

Comment: @raj why do we need version < 2.0 of jquery as well? Is that dependant on which angular version you are using? According to angular's faqs [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq) from angular 1.3 it's recommended that you only use jquery verion >= 2.1.
Also can you please let me know where you got this info from? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just a shot here, but make sure you do not have compatibility mode turned on. I wasted some time on a similar error, and had accidentally clicked the compatibility button when I meant to click on the refresh button.

Answer (score 0):

for Angularjs working correctly in Internet Explorer you also need jQuery version which is under 2.0.  Here is the solution which works for me.

```
<head>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
   <script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/jquery.1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gte IE 9]><!-->
   <script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/jquery.2.0.min.js"></script>
<!--<![endif]-->
<title>App Title</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/jquery.plugin.min.js"></script>
```